# Android: How to set checked boxes when using CHOICE_MODE_NONE

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with checkboxes that has type CHOICE_MODE_NONE, because I want to make each item tri-state.
It works fine using setChecked in onItemClick, to check and uncheck the items as required.

But when starting up the view, I want to set some items. The problem is that setItemChecked is only valid if CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE or CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE.
So how do I check an item?

I tried the following, but ck is null:

```
int totalItems = getListView().getCount();
if (totalItems > 0)
{
    for (int position=0; position<totalItems; position++)
    {
        CheckedTextView ck = (CheckedTextView)(lv.getChildAt(position));
        ck.setChecked(true);
        }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What excactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it, thanks to http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/
 - overriding the arrayadapter gave me access to the view of each item on the list.

So I was able to write:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    if (v == null) 
    {
        v = super.getView(position, v, parent);
    }
    CheckedTextView tv = (CheckedTextView) v;
    tv.setChecked(passengers.get(position).isPassengerOnBoard());
    return v;
}
```